# Has anyone seen GAE fail to respect the deadline attribute of an RPC?

Tags: image, google-app-engine

I occasionally get timeouts when trying to do transforms or resizes on large images using `Image.execute_transforms_async` (https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/images/imageclass#Image_execute_transforms_async).

I tried adding a deadline to my `create_rpc` call, but it seems to ignore it.  Here's the code snippet:

`image_data_rpc = images.create_rpc(deadline=5)
image.execute_transforms_async(output_encoding=image_output_type, quality=95, rpc=image_data_rpc)`

I've seen this work with urlfetch, wonder if I'm missing something here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We eventually figured this out.  It wasn't that the deadline wasn't being respected, it was that the call to `execute_transforms_async` itself was timing out.  The call to `image_data_rpc.get_result()` was only occurring after a deadline exceeded error.  Still trying to figure out the cause of the timeout on `execute_transforms_async`, but the deadline parameter seems to be working as expected.